# How to Code a Wikimedia Link So It Opens in a New Tab or Window

Tags: wikimedia

I'm using a wiki based on the wikimedia engine, i.e same wiki technology used by wikipedia.

How do I code a link in the wiki language that will open the target URL in a new window or tab. Essentially, I want the wiki language equivalent of:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="new">Google</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

You mean like this
    [http://www.example.org link name]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do what I'm looking for. That syntax opens the target page in the same tab; I want to figure out the wiki syntax to open the page in a new tab.

Comment: Look here  http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_make_external_links_open_in_a_new_window.3F